# SCOM: It won't invoke an external module

Tags: scom

I have a simple .exe on a network share that merely creates a dummy file on a network share. The program works. I've wrapped it in a .bat file, a .ps1 file, and a .vbs file, and they all work. However, when I create a SCOM rule to invoke any of these beasts it does not run. Am I missing a management pack or building the rule wrong such that SCOM doesn't run my module? What's the secret to having SCOM run an external module? Thanks.

Comment: Re-Import the MP and watch the operations manager event log on the agent for errors. Also confirm the run as account is able to the .vbs script.

Comment: The Operations Manager event log has nothing in it about my rule, and I don't have permissions to re-import the MP or find out the run-as account. I bet you're onto it with the run-as account, though. I'll check with someone who should know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, Does your SCOM Agent's RunAs account have permission to access the file?
Most folks deploy the SCOM agent and leave it running under a local account.

Second, if this is a custom authored rule, is your rule properly configured to run on the target system or is it running on the management server? ( what is your target? )

With the basics covered, I have a hunch that your SCOM rule is executing PowerShell based on your use of 'invoke'. If you run PowerShell remotely without enabling CredSSP then you wont be able to make an authenticated connection to the file share downstream.

This guy explains it better then I can: https://4sysops.com/archives/using-credssp-for-second-hop-powershell-remoting/

If this is not the issue can you paste in the actual action the rule is taking?

Comment: The answer is somewhat decent, but asking for additional information on a 9 months old question is unlikely to contribute much. Consider turning your questions into descriptions (from "Do you XYZ?" into "a possible cause is XYZ, fix by doing ABC")